# CMake: Linking a third-party library to a project library

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I am currently working on a C++ project using CMake as its build system.

The projects consists of several output executables, each having relatively little custom code, but leveraging a few common libraries:

```
programX
|
├── CMakeLists.txt (this contains the main executable targets)
|
├── Engine
│   ├── ...
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
|
├── Utils
│   ├── third_party (this is what I added)
│   │   └── backward-cpp
│   |       └ CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── ...
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
|
└── etc.
```

The main functionality of the project is contained inside an `Engine` library which is statically linked to the main executables using something like `target_link_libraries(programX Engine)`. Many utilities are also contained in a separate `Utils` library.

I have added a CMake dependency to one of these project libraries (it's the [backward-cpp](https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp) stacktrace prettifier). That project is also built using CMake.

In the interest of modularity, I have added the `backward-cpp` project as a dependency to the only project library which actually uses it, `Utils`. I did this in order not to "pollute" the main `CMakeLists.txt` file with directives only pertaining to a small part of the project.

My `Utils/CMakeLists.txt` therefore looks like this:

```
SET(UTILS_HEADERS ...)
set(UTILS_OBJECTS Dummy.cpp ${UTILS_HEADERS})

# This is the new dependency!
add_subdirectory(third_party/backward-cpp)

SOURCE_GROUP("" FILES ${UTILS_HEADERS})

# 'BACKWARD_ENABLE' and 'add_backward' are needed for linking.
add_library(Utils ${UTILS_OBJECTS} ${BACKWARD_ENABLE})
add_backward(Utils)
```

Doing this, however, does not work, and the project ends up not linking (the symbols from the `backward-cpp` library are not found), *unless* I link the output executables to the third party library directly, in the root `CMakeLists.txt` file (`add_backward(MainExecutableA-Z)`).

I am aware that one cannot link static libraries to other static libraries, but I would be interested in knowing if there is a nice way to achieve this modularization of static libraries and their dependencies using CMake.

(Alternatively, I could always just link everything directly to the main targets, since that always works.)

### Update (May 22nd 2017)

I've managed to get everything working now, with `backwards-cpp` being controlled 100% from the "narrowest" `CMakeLists.txt` file, thanks to the helpful answers I got. Here's the `Utils/CMakeLists.txt` file I ended up with (non-relevant parts removed):

```
SET(UTILS_HEADERS ...)   
SET(UTILS_SOURCES ...)


# If enabled, enables sensible stack traces on Linux, complete with corresponding source
# code, where available. CUDA errors also produce complete stack traces when this is on.
# If disabled, the error messages degrade gracefully to file/line information.
OPTION(WITH_BACKWARDS_CPP "Build with backwards-cpp stack trace dumping library? (Linux-only)" TRUE)
message(STATUS "backwards-cpp-enhanced stack traces? " ${WITH_BACKWARDS_CPP})

if(WITH_BACKWARDS_CPP)
  # Support 'backward-cpp,' a lean stacktrace printing library for Linux.
  add_definitions(-DWITH_BACKWARDS_CPP)
  add_subdirectory(third_party/backward-cpp)
endif()

SOURCE_GROUP("" FILES ${UTILS_HEADERS} ${UTILS_SOURCES})
add_library(Utils ${UTILS_HEADERS} ${UTILS_SOURCES})

# ...unrelated CUDA stuff...

if(WITH_BACKWARDS_CPP)
  # Link agains libbfd to ensure backward-cpp can extract additional information from the binary,
  # such as source code mappings. The '-lbfd' dependency is optional, and if it is disabled, the
  # stack traces will still work, but won't show unmangled symbol names or source code snippets.
  # You may need to set BACKWARD_USE_BFD to 0 in its `hpp` and `cpp` files to avoid linker errors.
  target_link_libraries(Utils PUBLIC -lbfd)
  target_link_libraries(Utils PUBLIC backward)
endif()
```

Comment: If I understood well, you succesfully built and linked the Utils static library but received linker errors when tried to link the main executable. Am I right?

Comment: The Utils lib always builds OK. I can also build the main executables, but only if I link them directly with both Utils, and the third party lib. The transitive part, when I attempt to just link Utils to the third party lib, and the main executables with Utils, is the one that doesn't work.

Comment: Well, according to my knowledge, a static library doesn't link with other static libraries, therefore when you build your executable, you need to link it with all of your static libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [README of backward-cpp](https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp/blob/master/README.md), I would try the following (only the last two lines change):

```
SET(UTILS_HEADERS ...)
set(UTILS_OBJECTS Dummy.cpp ${UTILS_HEADERS})

# This is the new dependency!
add_subdirectory(third_party/backward-cpp)

SOURCE_GROUP("" FILES ${UTILS_HEADERS})

add_library(Utils ${UTILS_OBJECTS})
target_link_libraries(Utils PUBLIC backward)
```

Note that `PUBLIC` in the last statement takes care of setting the include directories and link libraries when you link other targets against `Utils`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, using this leads to a problem with `target_link_libraries`, since it expects `Backward::Backward` to be a target (`Target "Utils" links to target "Backward::Backward" but the target was not found. `). However, attempting to use the second approach from the README, the "Modifying CMAKE_MODULE_PATH" one, also doesn't work, as CMake then fails to find the backward package. Is it necessary to write a custom `FindBackward.cmake` file to put in `/cmake`?

Comment: and what if you replace `Backward::Backward` by `backward`?

Comment: Yes, using just `backward` in the last line did the trick. I had to solve a couple of subsequent issues regarding linking `libbfd` (necessary for prettier stack traces) and adding a compile-time flag for toggling the use of `backwards-cpp`, but I managed to get it working. Thank you! I've updated my answer with my current `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Answer (score 2):

After looking inside the [BackwardConfig.cmake](https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp/blob/master/BackwardConfig.cmake) and reading the project's [README](https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp/blob/master/README.md) I came to the conclusion that the most easy way to link your executable with the **Backward-cpp** is using the `add_backward(target)` macro as you mentioned in your question.

The other option described under **Modifying CMAKE_MODULE_PATH** subtitle in the [README](https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp/blob/master/README.md) shuld work as well but I not tested. The `find_package` in *Config* mode will search for file called `<name>Config.cmake` which is `BackwardConfig.cmake` in this case, so you don't have to write any extra CMake modules like `FindBackward.cmake`. As a try I would do the following:

```
set(UTILS_HEADERS ...)
set(UTILS_OBJECTS Dummy.cpp ${UTILS_HEADERS})

source_group("" FILES ${UTILS_HEADERS})
add_library(Utils ${UTILS_OBJECTS})

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /path/to/backward-cpp)
find_package(Backward)

target_link_libraries(Utils PUBLIC Backward::Backward)
```